# Wired connection started failing out of nowhere

Tags: network-manager, internet, ethernet, wired

Just today I ditched Windows 10 for Ubuntu 20.04 LTS on my custom PC; I installed Ubuntu via a bootable stick: minimal installation.

Everything went great installation-wise! I got it up and running; set some GNOME themes for my desktop/shell, and installed some apps.

After a while; my wired connection just stopped working: it stays on *Wired Connecting* for a bit and then prompts "Activation of network connection failed". I know it's not my Network: as all my mobile and wired devices work.

I don't have a separate Wireless or Ethernet card: the Ethernet port comes with the Motherboard; it's a **Gigabyte F2A68HM-H**.

I googled around but couldn't find any answer - I'm loving Linux so far but without an Internet connection I can't do much.

Thanks in advance for your support!

*P.D I'm also getting a System Crash Report on startup - if that's relevant.*

Comment: First let us know what Ubuntu did you install.  If it worked for a while then quit I am guessing it is a hardware failure. Try reseating the cable on both ends a few times and see if both lights flash on the port on the desktop. That flash is hardware based and will help you tell if the issue is software or not.

Comment: @walttheboss Sorry! I installed 20.04 LTS; light is as always: Steady green, flashing orange.

Comment: OK great.  Now go to the network and create a new connection. Don't change any settings.  Let it do it.  Then see if that connects.

Comment: @walttheboss No result, still showing the same prompt.

Comment: OK good work troubleshooting. I normally use the normal(not minimal) installation. I think it comes with more features.  Could be you need an "Additional Driver".  BUT with no internet connection you don't have much luck.  Try a bootable USB normal download and see if your ethernet works.  If it does then you probably need a new install from the normal download.

Comment: @walttheboss Thank you for your help! Is it possible to get the drivers on a USB and install them on my computer? Also, in the case that I reinstall; do I need to wipe my drive or can I install over the current OS?

Comment: You can if you know exactly what drivers you need.  And since it did work once for a while then the drivers are probably there.  Could be they were for some reason blacklisted.  If you do a reinstall I think you can safely install over your existing.  If you do a two partition install(/ and /home) then format / and do not format /home. BUT if you don't have lots on there then I recommend doing a normal install formatting both paritions during the install.  AND use the normal installer.  BUT first try with the DVD to see if ethernet works.  If not something else is wrong.

Comment: @walttheboss I’m installing over my existing: Ethernet works on the live boot - I’m doing the normal + 3rd party support. Let’s hope that works!

Comment: Well done. That spirit of moving forward and learning will serve you well as you enter the world of Ubuntu.

Comment: @walttheboss I hope so - haha because its testing me now! Install just finished and the connection keeps failing. What can I do now?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/110079/discussion-between-walttheboss-and-fslowkey-byte).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are a few steps to try:

1. Unplug and replug the ethernet cable. (Do you have both lights on?)
2. Run ifconfig to see if the connection is there.
3. Disable ipv6 in Network Settings to make sure there is no router conflict.
4. Find an alternate way to connect to the internet.  Update everythying.
5. Look in /etc/modprobe.d to see if your Ethernet device is blacklisted.
6. Change the ethernet cable.

It turned out to be a bad cable!!  SOLVED